# Help drawing an Electronic System with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this Code:

```
% Title: Block diagram of Third order noise shaper in Compact Disc Players
% Author: Ramón Jaramillo
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}
%Blocks
\tikzset{%
  block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, minimum height = 3em,
    minimum width = 3em},
  circle/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm},
}

%Symbols
\renewcommand{\sum}{\Large$+$}
\newcommand{\cross}{\Large$\times$}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
%nodes
\node [] (start) at (0,0) {};
\node [circle, right of=start] (plus) {\cross};
\node at (7,0)[] (end) {};
\node at (6.8,0)[] (send) {};
\node [block, below of=send] (T) {T};
%##### I don't know how to place the last node - it should be in the midlle between plus and send and 2x the distance from send to T.
%arrows
\draw[->] (start) -- (plus);
\draw[->] (plus) -- (end);
\draw[--] (send) -- (T);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And it should look like this at the end:
[image: Tikzexample]

But at the left side of the node (start) there should be the letter a, and a letter b at the right side of the node (end) and there should be a short horizontal arrow showing on the cross (which I couldn't draw).

**Problems**
It didn't compile. And I don't know how to make the last note. And I don't know how to put the labels on. And I don't know how to make the arrows change direction.

Thank you very much in advance! Kind regards!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like that?

[image]

The main problem with your code is the redefinition of `circle` which calls `circle`. I replaced it by `my circle`. For the elements, I used absolute positioning which is not so elegant, but allows all degrees of freedom.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}
%Blocks
\tikzset{%
  block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, minimum height = 3em,
    minimum width = 3em},
  my circle/.style   = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm},
}

%Symbols
\renewcommand{\sum}{\Large$+$}
\newcommand{\cross}{\Large$\times$}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
\node (start) at (0,0) {a};
\node[my circle] (plus) at (2,0) {\sum};
\node[my circle] (times) at (4,-2) {\cross};
\node[block] at (6.5,-1) (T) {T};
\node (end) at (8,0) {b};
\coordinate (send) at (6.5,0);
\draw[->] (start) -- (plus);
\draw[->] (plus) -- (end);
\draw (send) -- (T);
\draw[->] (T) |- (times);
\draw[->] (times) -| (plus);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```